# Is the TLS-PSK ciphersuite supported in .NET?

Tags: .net, ssl, network-programming, tls-psk

We are planning to use the TLS-PSK ciphersuite for TLS communication.
Is it supported within the .NET framework? 
 Documentation on the web is very rare.
We are currently using :NET framework version 4.6.2, but can also upgrade to newer versions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Is it supported within the .NET framework?" Both yes and no. For example, ECDHE ciphers have been supported by Windows for a long while, and `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpClient` can use them to talk HTTPS (via Windows API). However, the actual ECDHE algorithms are exposed as new classes only in latest .NET Framework releases. TLS_PSK is just a similar case.

Comment: @LexLi we use .Net Framework v 4.5.2. Is there exist TLS-PSK support? Maybe we can use third-party library to implement this feature. Do you know any libraries to do it?

Comment: @LexLi I have found a third-party library. Please review documentation [here](http://www.networkcomms.net/using-encryption/). Maybe we can use this library for PSK?

Comment: @Lex Li Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately I was not able to get TLS_PSK working in .NET 4.7.2.  
The documentation for SslStream class does not give any hint on that topic. Or at least I dont see it.  
[Doku SslStream class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx)  
Can you please provide me with some more information about how to get TLS-PSK working in .NET?  
Thank you!